# how spring standalone application is running without xsd?

Tags: spring

I am running spring test application in which I have used Spring 3.1.2 and in context xml added spring-context-3.1.xsd. Now for my testing I have removed all .xsd files (spring-context-2.5.xsd, spring-context-3.0.xsd, spring-context-3.1.xsd) from all spring jar files which are in classpath. But still spring application is running without any error.

Now again changed xsd version in context xml from 3.1 to 3.0 and then application failed to start.

Why spring application is running without any spring xsd file in classpath?

Note: All tests are performed without any network connectivity. So no question about getting xsd file from www.springframework.org

Yogesh

Comment: so you have only spring-beans jar in your classpath where you've deleted all xsds inside? Also what are you trying to achieve with this activity?

Comment: What makes you think that it wouldn't run without the xsd files? They are just grammar constraints for your xml files (which are needed). Spring might just be able to ignore the missing files and stile parse your xml files. Without looking into the Spring sources there is no compelling reason to assume the xsd files are needed.

Comment: Can you show your context xml? In my projects the xsd are related to http://something.com/...